# Show a constant admob ad banner in all the activities

Tags: java, android, admob

I am working on an android application, i have embedded admob ad at the bottom of each activity and its shows ad in all activities, but i want to show a constant admob ad in all the activities that displays all the time without destroy itself during switching activities, please help me if any one know the solution for this problem, i have 3 activities and i also try to create a base class and extends all activities with this base class and call the function which creates and load the ad, but still the same issue i have to call this function from every activity class so every time it sends request to load ad and display just on the desire activity from which it calls, i need to show a one ad on all the three activities, thanx in advance....

Comment: You might want to consider if you actually need to display an advert in all of your activities. For instance, putting a banner advert at the bottom of your 'settings' or 'about' screen probably isn't the greatest idea.

Comment: i am using viewPager its look obvious that all three pages have 3 different ads at the bottom, thats why i want just one constant ad in all the three pages, any suggestion

Comment: If you're using ViewPager are you not using Fragments? If this is the case, you could include the ad as part of the activity, and it would persist as you switch out the fragments.

Comment: Yes i am using fragments, give me some example code plz

Comment: Just display the advert in your activity's onCreate method and it won't be destroyed as you switch out the fragments.

Comment: in all the activities or in the main activity only???

Comment: What I'm saying is, if your user will spend the majority of their time in one activity that switches between multiple fragments using a ViewPager, you should display the ad in the activity and it will then appear in all the fragments... but it sounds like you **do** want the ad to appear in multiple activities (which is what you said initially, but I thought you might have been meaning multiple fragments when you talking about the ViewPager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this.
And as Ellis says you only want to display an ad where your user spends most of their time.

Comment: thanks for replying...! I have considered a lot of apps that have a constant ad at the bottom, and it didn't destroy during switching activities...! then the question is that how they are doing this if you say there is no way to do this????

Comment: Do you have an example of an app that does this?

Comment: Husnain it sounds like you are confused about the difference between an Activity and a View. You can most certainly have an Activity with an AdView at the bottom and a ViewPager at the top which switches the contents of the ViewPager. But that is not the same as multiple Activities with the same AdView which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you. Give this code a try. Also, if required, try using the child fragment approach to View Pager.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


            <include android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"     layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container21" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        < com.myapp.isgreat.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout android:id="@+id/scrimInsetsFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_gravity="start" app:insetForeground="#4000"
            android:elevation="10dp">
            <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
                android:name="com.my.appisgreat.NavigationDrawerFragment"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
        </com.myapp.isgreat.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps..!
Happy Android development.!

Answer (score 1):

There may be one way to do this. But for that, you might need to completely restructure your app UI. You could keep one activity in your app, and convert all the actual activities into fragments. Then, you will just swap fragments inside the same single activity.
I wouldn't recommend this though.